# PayPal sandbox doesn't show payment options

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Whenever I try to pay using the following button:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="facilitators@somemail.com">

<!-- Specify a Subscribe button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<!-- Identify the subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Alice's Weekly Digest">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="DIG Weekly">

<!-- Set the terms of the regular subscription. -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">

<!-- Set recurring payments until canceled. -->
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">

<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_subscribe_113x26.png"
alt="Subscribe">
```

it seems like it's logging me in to view my account instead of providing the options to pay :/

I remember this working in the past... Anyone had this issue before?

Thanks!

Comment: We had a known issue at PayPal's end which is causing this issue. The engineering team is working on this issue for a fix. No ETA at the moment. Will update here once the issue gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the info @PP_Punna! Strange nobody else seems to have this reported here

Comment: This issue has been resolved. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @PP_Punna !! I could manage to do the payment but I don't see the payments in my sanbox :/ Also I don't think that ipn is sent. Can you please confirm this?

Comment: can you please file an MTS ticket at our MTS portal: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/  with the seller, buyer email address. So that our engineers will help you further. Thanks.